# How do starships always know which way is 'up'?

Tags: star-trek

When starships meet in space, they are always topside in the same way. Wouldn't it be totally random? I can understand when a ship is in orbit that the planet is 'down', but even then, it should make no difference.

Comment: The duplicate question has answers that explain this well in *Star Trek* and other fictional universes with artificial gravity. I just want to point out that in our universe and other more realistic fictional universes (*The Expanse* comes to mind), "topside" for a thrusting spaceship would always be the direction it is traveling, not perpendicular like in *Star Trek*.